# Checking if data exists at a table and then comparing it on a seperate table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Players and achievements.

At the players table there is the player name field and at the achievement table there is also a player name field.

So the same name is on both tables.

I purged some players which were inactive and deleted their data. Now the thing is, I have a lot of useless data at my achievements table since I was not using foreign keys, when I deleted their data at the players table their data at the achievements table was not deleted and there's useless data at the achievement table.

What I need is, the query that will delete rows at the achievement table if they don't exist at the players table.

So if a player's name is on the achievements table, however not at the players table, the data on the achievements table will be deleted.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

What I need is, the query that will delete rows at the achievement table if they don't exist at the players table.

One version using join

```
delete t1
 from Achivemntes t1
left join
players t2
on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

Comment: Actually how does this compare with the names? Because I need the query to get the name from the achievement table and then look at the player table. If that name does not exist at the players table then the data is supposed to be deleted. Not if the same id does not exist.

Comment: left join with the where clause i kept ,gives me rows which are in achivements ,but not in players table.

Comment: you may need to update your question with test data and show how those two tables are linked

Comment: that was not what I needed XD ahah. I needed the query to grab the username  from the achievements table and then look at the players table and see if there is data at that table with that name and if there is not then delete it from the achievements table